# error in my project java The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, double

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("the result is: \n" + num1 - num2);
```

The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) String, double

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do here corresponds to

```
("the result is: \n" + num1) - num2
```

in which `num1` gets cast to a string and added to your first String. Afterwards, you try to subtract an int or something from a String which is not defined.

You can fix this by using proper parentheses settings

```
"the result is: \n" + (num1 - num2)
```

So that the subtraction of `num1- num2` is done before the Cast to String and the concatenation

Answer (score 1):

`num1 - num2` is an equation that needs to be in brackets , because you need to add the result of it to the string , so the code should be like this

```
System.out.println("the result is: \n" + (num1 - num2));
```